# Submit form with multiple submit buttons in Windows CE

Tags: javascript, mobile, windows-ce

I have an application, running on a mobile device (scanner) with Windows CE and IE Mobile Browser:
This **generated** HTML-Code is statis, so I cannot change anything here:

```
<form method="post" name="myForm" action="/sap(...=)/.../example/.../~...=">
 <div id="buttons">.
  <input class="okay" id="SubmitButton" type=submit name="~OKCode=CONFRM" value="Select">
  <input class="back" id="BackButton" type=submit name="~OKCode=BACK" value="Back">
 </div>
  ... other forms datas ...
</form>
```

I want to submit the form when the user press a specific key, so I added this Javascript:

```
function navigate(){
  document.onkeyup = function(event) {
    if (event.keyCode == '55') {
      var myButton = document.getElementById("SubmitButton");
      myButton.click();
    }
    if (event.keyCode == '57') {
      var myButton = document.getElementById("BackButton");
      myButton.click();
    }
  }
}
```

This sulution works in all browsers on a Computer, but not on my mobile scanner.

I guess the problem is caused by not supported function click() to submit a form in Windows CE. Does someon have a other idea to submit the form by using this specific Submit-Buttons with keydown() ??

thanks!

Comment: did you try myButton.form.submit() ?

Comment: with myButton.form.sumit() the result ist the same as form.submit()